# Rule to find the tangent line of a function

Tags: calculus

Let's suppose that we have the function
$x^2$.
We can write $x^2$ like $$\left(\frac {x^\frac {2}{x}}{1^\frac {1}{x}}\right)^x.$$
Now we may construct a new function: $$\left(\frac {x^\frac {2}{x}}{1^\frac {1}{x}}\right)^{x^3}.$$ 
Both functions touch each other in the points they meet, that is, their derivatives in those points are the same as well.

Another example. For $2x^2$ the new function is
$$\left(\frac{2^{1/x}x^{2/x}}{1^{1/x}}\right)^{2x^3}.$$

In general, the new function of
$ax^b$ is 
$$\left(\frac {a^{1/x}\cdot x^{b/x}}{1^{1/x}}\right)^{ax^{b+1}}. $$

Both touch in their common points.

But why does this rule work?
Any algebraic explanation?

Comment: What you have written as "an arbitrary tangent line" doesn't look like a linear equation to me. The word "implies" is usually followed (and preceded) by a statement that can be either true or false, not an expression. So, for several reasons, I find this post very hard to understand.

Comment: You can’t really rewrite $x^2$ that way: your alternate expression is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: What I mean by ARBITRARY tangent line is that it just has one point of intersection and that it has the same slope at that point. And it is logic that it's undefined at x=0, because you wouldn't have a function: $p*0^a=0$. And when you write a function like $x^2$ like the way that I did, the function is only defined at x>0, but that's fine because you only want an arbitrary tangent line of the original function.

Comment: Try to graph a random function $ax^b$ and graph a second function by applying that rule to the first function. You will see that it works.

Comment: There’s a typo, it should read $x^\frac{b}{x}$.

Comment: No it's correct, it's just a bit unclear in the example.

Comment: O, it’s incorrect.  Give it a plot with $a=3$ and $b=4$.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Was a bit confused. I will correct it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because what you've written makes no sense (to me). You use calculus to find tangent lines: the derivative tells you the slope at any point.

Comment: Instead of instantly voting to close the question, you could also ask questions. But anyway, the rule gives you a function which is an arbitrary, curvy tangent line. I was wondering why this rule works. I don't care about the derivates or calculating the slope, but what I mean by tangent line is that when it intersects with the function, it has the same slope and only one point of intersection. Hence 'arbitrary, curvy tangent line'

Comment: @EthanBolker I object.  The OP tells us his thoughts a bit complicated, but has discovered something nice, see my answer, please.

Comment: OK I'll reverse my vote to close.

Comment: @Stallmp And I am wondering how you’ve come to your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a very nice generalization to your question.  Your function 
$$\left(\frac {a^{1/x}\cdot x^{b/x}}{1^{1/x}}\right)^{ax^{b+1}}$$
is actually $(ab^x)^{(ab^x)}$.  Therefore let us consider $f(x)^{f(x)}$ for a function $f$ for which $f^f$ does exist.

We will show a fact that was previously unknown at least to me:

> In every point which $f$ and $f^f$ share, $f$ touches $f^f$, that is, their derivatives in their common points are equal as well.

We find first that $f(x)^{f(x)}=f(x)$ iff $f(x)=1$, hence $f(x)^{f(x)}=1$ here. In case they meet it must be on the line $y=1$.

The derivative of $f^f$ is calculated as usual to

$$\bigl(f^f\bigr)’=f^f\cdot f’\cdot\bigl(\ln(f)+1\bigr).$$

In each common point we find that
$$\bigl(f(x)^{f(x)}\bigr)’=1\cdot f’(x)\bigl(\ln(1)+1\bigr)=f’(x),$$
which was to be shown.

Feel free to draw some pictures, nice ones involve $\sin$ as $f(x)=x\cdot \sin(x)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do you proof that $ax^b$ always has ONE point of intersection with $(ax^b)^{ax^b} $?

Comment: @Stallmp That’s easy, you just have to solve $ax^b=1$ for $x$.  Feel free to accept my answer, please.

Comment: Why do you solve it like that?

Comment: As usual: $x=\sqrt[b]{1/a}$.